# Data not changing correctly in VBA, showing ####

Tags: json, excel, vba, jira-rest-api

I have some dates I pulled from a JSON data set in the form of (2017-04-03T15:36:45.000+0000) and I am turning it into the form (dd/mm/yy), this is the code I have so far.

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(5) = Date
For i = 1 to Json("issues").Count
    Dim date_thing As String, date_part As String, finD As Date
    date_thing =  Json("issues")(i)("fields")("resolutiondate")

    date_part = Split (date_thing, "T")(0)
    finD = DateSerial(Split(date_part, "-")(0), Split(date_part, "-")(2), 
    Split(date_part, "-")(1))
    
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i+1, 5) = finD
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i+1, 5).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy" 
Next i
```

For some reason two of the dates don't get formatted correctly and just come out as "#######." They are **"2020-06-12T23:44:00.000+0000"** and **"2020-04-10T21:37:31.000+0000"**. What could be wrong?

Comment: Which is your local default data format? Do the dates which are corrected displayed have the middle number bigger then the last one?

Comment: Try please the idea I suggested in my answer, in order to not let Excel guessing which is day and which is month...

Answer (score 0):

Dealing only with strings, when you try formatting, Excel only guesses which is the day and the month... I think, you must tell to him which is each of them. Try, please, the next approach:

```
Dim d As String, date_part As String, finD As Date
   d = "2020-06-12T23:44:00.000+0000" 'only for testing reason. You use Json...
   date_part = Split(d, "T")(0)
   finD = DateSerial(Split(date_part, "-")(0), Split(date_part, "-")(2), Split(date_part, "-")(1))
   Debug.Print Format(finD, "dd/mm/yy")
   ActiveSheet.Cells(i+1, 5).value = finD
   ActiveSheet.Cells(i+1, 5).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"
```

I did not understand which is your month and day. If it will not return what you need, just switch the middle term with the last one...

In this way, Excel must not guess anymore. It will always consider the second term being month/day, as you 'instruct' it.

Comment: How do I print the "Debug.Print Format(finD, "dd/mm/yy")" because right now I'm just populating the dates into the cells via "ActiveSheet.Cells(i+1, 5) = findD

Comment: While of course it is working, I think you shouldn't repeat the `Split`-command 3 times - instead, use an intermediate variable. Makes it much easier to read.

Comment: @ben101: Unless you really need strings in your Excel, you should write the result of the `DateSerial` into Excel. This way, the value is stored as `Date`, not as `String` that looks like a Date. You can set the number format of the cell to match the way you want to display it.

Comment: @FaneDuru: Nope, it's a string. The result of `Format` is a string, and that string is written into the cell. And depending on language settings and Excel version it *may* be seen as date. Always write a date as date and apply formatting, else the next question on SO is not far away.

Comment: It still did not work now I have other ones that are in error too, including "2017-11-30T11:29:46.000+0000", "2020-05-22T23:22:05.000+0000", and "2020-05-28T21:13:01.000+0000"

Comment: @ben101 Debug.print allows you to see the result. In Immediate window (being in VBE: Ctrl + G will show Immediate window). If it does what you need, you will use: ActiveSheet.Cells(i+1, 5) = finD' followed by `ActiveSheet.Cells(i+1, 5) .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"`

Comment: @FunThomas: You are right!. It should use cell `NumberFormat` as date in the format he needs...

Comment: @ben101: I thought it is enough to see the way of string manipulation and I was wrong when I recommended to use the same format in cell. Please, see my updated code... Refresh the page (this one) before.

Comment: That is odd some of that previously working dates are now printing the wrong thing for example "2017-04-27T03:01:41.000+0000" is now printing "04/03/19" and "2020-06-26T18:59:46.000+0000" is printing "06/02/22"

Comment: @ben101: I would say, this is not possible... Can you edit your question and post the code you used? Against the Json returned string. Try using `Debug.Print` before processing it as shown above. The year is the first argument of `DateValue`. It cannot be changed in any circumstance. How do you know that `date_thing` is the one you say?

Comment: @ben101:  **How do you know that the Json string associated to the Date returned is the one you say**? I tested my code and it works as expected. But, did you try to also switch 'Split(date_part, "-")(2)` with `Split(date_part, "-")(1)`?

Comment: @ben101: Do you have an answer to the above question? Are you sure about the string to pe processed against the processed date?

Answer (score 0):

Don't want to steal FaneDurus answer, but too much to put in a comment.

So your task is to convert a `String` into a `Date`. A `Date` is stored as number (double) internally and you have a lot of possibilities to format it in any way you like, to calculate with it and so on.

So the `String` you get is something like `"2020-05-28T21:13:01.000+0000"`. It is important to remember that technically this is a `String`, not a `Date`. Excel is good at guessing a date from a string, but it cannot do miracles, so to be sure you are on the save side, split the string by yourself using `String functions`.

There are many ways to do so, but I think the easiest way is to use the `Split`-command (as FaneDuru did). First step is to separate the *Date* and the *Time* part, you did this already:

```
dateTimeParts = Split(date_thing, "T")
```

Now we have an array with 2 elements, first one (index=0) has `"2020-05-28"` and the second (index=1) has `"21:13:01.000+0000"`. Next step is to split the date part into year, month and day. They are separated by a dash, so we use

```
Dim dateParts() as string
dateParts = split(dateTimeParts(0), "-")
```

Now you have 3 strings in `dateParts`, one holding the year, one the month and one the day. Next task is to create a real `Date` from those 3 parts, and VBA provides the `DateSerial` function for that: It creates a date from 3 numbers. You could feed it with the three strings you have in `dateParts`, however those as still strings. VBA will try to convert them, but it's better to write this down in code - implicit conversion is a source of many errors. For better readability, I use three intermediate variables, that's a matter of taste, but I prefer not to put to many operations in one line. The `CLng` will convert a `String` into a `Long`:

```
Dim day as long, month as long, year as long, finalDate as Date
year = CLng(dateParts(0))
month = CLng(dateParts(1))
day = CLng(dateParts(2))
finalDate = dateSerial(year, month, day)
```

Now you want to write the date into a cell and it should be displayed in a form "DD/MM/YY". Don't convert the precious `Date` back into a string (as the `Format`-function would do). Instead, write the date value into a cell and format the cell so that the date is shown in the way you want. I assume `ActiveCell`, adapt it to whatever cell you need, but please don't use `Select` to set the `ActiveCell`).

```
Activecell.Value = finalDate
Activecell.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"
```

That way, you can change the format of the cell later (for example use a 4-digits date) without a problem, or change the format to that the name of the day or month is written. This changes only the way how the date is displayed - the date value itself remains unchanged.